# Как получить данные из БД-MySql в ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, mysql

Задача: получить данные из БД-MySql в ObservableCollection и затем передать в DataGrid.

Код:

```
    public class Games: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string price;
        public string Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

public class SearchGames
{
    private ObservableCollection<Games> _gamesCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Games> GamesCollection
    {
        get { return _gamesCollection; }
        set { _gamesCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }        

    public void SearchGames()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM GamesTable";
            command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var game = new Games
                {
                    Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                    Price= row["Price"].ToString()
                };
                GamesCollection.Add(game);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: А чего тут не понятного? Получили данные из базы, далее проходим по этим данным циклом и каждую итерацию сверяем с объектом в  ObservableCollection, если он есть - обновляем данные уже существующего, если нету - добавляем новый. Ну а так у вас сейчас вопрос смело можно разбить на 3: 1. Как получить данные. 2. Как из коллекции в коллекцию добавить данные. 3. Как привязать коллекцию. А это означает, что вопрос слишком общий...

Comment: Вот вы обновили вопрос. Подумайте сами, нам что либо это дало? Что конкретно у вас не получается и что вы ожидаете?

Comment: Ну, коллекция создана, данные из БД получены и занесены в эту коллекцию. Осталось сделать последний пункт. Неужто не осилите?

Comment: Все получилось. Надо было указать private ObservableCollection<Games> _gamesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Games>;

Comment: Верните вопрос, как был. А решение опубликуйте как ответ (и потом примите его).

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
    public class Games: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string price;
        public string Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

public class SearchGames
{
    private ObservableCollection<Games> _gamesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Games>;
    public ObservableCollection<Games> GamesCollection
    {
        get { return _gamesCollection; }
        set { _gamesCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }        

    public void SearchGames()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM GamesTable";
            command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var game = new Games
                {
                    Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                    Price= row["Price"].ToString()
                };
                GamesCollection.Add(game);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) `DataTable` и `adapter` не нужны, из `command` нужно получать ридер = `command.ExecuteReader()`. А потом использовать цикл `while(reader.Read()){..}`. 2) Всю работу с БД нужно вынести в отдельный класс, а не лепить лапша-код.